# unexpected output while making virtual keyboard using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, visual-studio-code

I was making my own virtual keyboard with python and open cv. I made a command that would change keyboard colour when we hover over it, but it didn't change colour. When I tell to print or make the font size large, then that's happening
this is my code
python
import cv2
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import keyboard
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Controller
import datetime
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 1280)
cap.set(4, 720)

```
finaltext = ""
keyboard = Controller()

detector = HandDetector(detectionCon=0.8, maxHands=1)
keys = [["Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P"],
        ["A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L",":"],
        ["Z","X","C","V","B","N","M",",",".","/"," "]]

def drawall(img, buttonlist):
    for Button in buttonlist:
        x,y = Button.pos
        w,h = Button.size
        cv2.rectangle(img, Button.pos ,(x+w,y+h) , (0,0,255),cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.putText(img, Button.text , (x+20,y+65), 
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255,255,255),4)
    return img


class button():
    def __init__(self , pos ,text , size=[85,85]):
        self.pos = pos
        self.size = size
        self.text = text




buttonlist = []
for i in range(len(keys)):
    for j, key in enumerate(keys[i]):
          buttonlist.append(button([100*j+50,100*i+50],key))



while True:
    success,img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img, draw=False)
    lmlist , bboxinfo = detector.findPosition(img)
    if lmlist:
        for Button in buttonlist:
            x,y = Button.pos
            w,h = Button.size           
            

            if x< lmlist[8][0]<x+w and y<lmlist[8][1]<y+h:
                cv2.rectangle(img, Button.pos ,(x+w,y+h) , (175,0,175),cv2.FILLED)
                cv2.putText(img, Button.text , (x+20,y+65), 
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255,255,0),4)
                #print("al is well")
                l,_,_ = detector.findDistance(8, 12, img,draw=False)
                #print(l)

                if l<45:
                    keyboard.press(Button.text)
                    cv2.rectangle(img, Button.pos ,(x+w,y+h) , (0,255,0),cv2.FILLED)
                    cv2.putText(img, Button.text , (x+20,y+65), 
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (255,255,0),4)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    
                    #print('done')
                    finaltext += Button.text
    cv2.rectangle(img, (50,350) ,(700,450) , (255,255,255),cv2.FILLED)
    cv2.putText(img, finaltext , (60,425), 
                            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 4, (0,0,0),4)
                            



    img = drawall(img, buttonlist)
    cv2.imshow("image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

As you can see, I have commented down 2 statements. Print all is well and done, but in the same line when I make it to change colour it doesn't. Actually, it is hiding behind the original colour, and also if could someone suggest to me how to terminate the task in vs code officially. I use Ctrl+c to do so in the terminal.

Thanks

Comment: this question looks familiar. have you posted this before, and then deleted it again?

Comment: Can you share the line of code with which you are changing the colour which is not working.?

Comment: @RahulKedia its not that  the line is not working when i put print hello in same line its does it

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz yes because that question was very inactive and dint get any answer it was actually dead so i posted it again hope you can help me

Comment: can't someone help me